# Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to load plain text from an outside file into my page and I keep getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong? (I followed the tutorial exactly!) Thanks.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Load" />

<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"AjaxRequest.html",
      success:function(data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
      }
    });
 });
```

EDIT: It is apparently no successful. Not sure why, the file is there right next to it.

Comment: I am guessing that the data returned in your success function of the $.ajax call is a full page (has an <html> tag in it).  You need to return html that is valid inside a <body> tag.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't show it in body tags.
When I put the tags in it still doesn't load.

Comment: @user1026288 that's not what John said. You need to insert content that is *valid inside of a document body*. Which means it can't contain `<html>` or `<body>`, those aren't nestable.

Comment: @hobbs sorry, misread, still though I did say "So I'm trying to load plain text from an outside file into my page..."
But yeah, either way it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that the click event is even being fired?  You may need to wrap that code in $(function() { // code goes here });

Comment: No, it wasn't being fired. With the addition of the $(function(){})}; it recognizes the click but gives the error in the title of the question.
I'm not sure how it's assigning anything to data. Debugging it shows that it's storing a "Document".

Comment: The tutorial I followed is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbQUJdimia4

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try specifying a dataType:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:"AjaxRequest.html",
      dataType:'html',
      success:function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: It helps me to fix bug in FF. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#content").append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
```

Comment: It's apparently not even hitting that line. Doesn't achieve success.